# com.restfb.exception.FacebookOAuthExceptioni when trying to get page insights using restfb api

Tags: restfb

Error:

> Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: Invalid parameter (code 100, subcode 1504016)

Code:

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken, Version.VERSION_2_5);
Connection<Insight> insights = facebookClient.fetchConnection("3954569608XXXX/insights", Insight.class,Parameter.with("since", "2016-08-01"),Parameter.with("until", "2017-03-10"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can directly give them as Strings. Convert that into datetime. I think, that will do it.